# Language used on a dagger hilt, supposedly of Persian provenance, ca. 1700-1750

Tags: weapons, middle-east, islam, identification, art

Could anyone guess what language is used in the sign made on this dagger hilt, supposedly of Persian provenance, and dated approx. 1700-1750?

A fellow translator asked if I knew, and naturally I don't know.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd say stylistically that looks similar to the Arabic script, but given the area that [would be expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script#Languages_written_with_the_Arabic_script) and doesn't really narrow it down any.

Comment: @T.E.D. I am an arab , the texture isnt arabic , it is not clear to be arabic words anyway.

Comment: it doesnt seems persian , i guess its ottoman ,take a look in the ottoman [coins](https://www.google.com.lb/search?q=ottoman+artifacts+1700&hl=en-LB&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjumJ6VqcHNAhUCYpoKHdVlCwQQ_AUIBigB#hl=en-LB&tbm=isch&q=ottoman+coins&imgdii=NGKeya2_CIgOnM%3A%3BNGKeya2_CIgOnM%3A%3B67vuyumq_KoRcM%3A&imgrc=NGKeya2_CIgOnM%3A) also the dagger seems ottoman too

Comment: This is no doubt an ignorant question, but how do you even know it's writing? Looks like it could be decoration to me

Comment: @NeMo - this is a good question, and I myself wondered if it might be just a motif, not a script.

Comment: Most of the letters a clearly arabic, but they aren't combined into meaningful words or even sentences. IMHO, this object is created by someone who wasn't able read and/or write arabic / farsi / urdu / turkish, for an audience that isn't able to, too. Do you assume this to be an authentic object, dating from 1700 - 1750? Is there any evidence of authenticity?

Comment: A question of going through these one by one... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_writing_system#Arabic_script

Comment: @tohuwawohu most helpful. is the letter order unambiguous at top?

Comment: @ tohuwawohu If they are letters but not words, is it possibly an acronym?  A dagger hilt doesn't provide much room to write long sentences so it would make sense to abbreviate somehow. Does Arabic have acronyms and were they used in the 1700s?

Comment: I should point out that the hilt has human figures carved on it, so it's unlikely to be made in an Islamic country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is stylistically typical of [Qajar period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qajar_dynasty), Persian walrus ivory [jambiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janbiya) hilts. 
As user @Spencer noted, human figures are rarely depicted in Islamic art other than in paintings. However [Qajar artworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qajar_art) were the exception that proved the rule, and exhibited significant European influence. Likewise, such hilts were commonly decorated with Gothic-esque reliefs, and inscribed in either **Persian or less comonly Arabic**, in the [nastaʿlīq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasta%CA%BFl%C4%ABq_script) or [taʿlīq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%CA%BFl%C4%ABq_script) scripts.

The inscriptions are often some relevant, cool sounding phrase. The [Metropolitan Museum of Art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_Museum_of_Art) holds [one item](https://wwwstg.metmuseum.org/exhibitions/view?exhibitionId=%7Bf9335363-16b7-41db-a7d9-6775cdc3e327%7D&oid=25032) where the nastaʿlīq inscription reads, "the handle of your dagger is world-seizing." [Harvard Art Museums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Art_Museums) has [one example](https://www.harvardartmuseums.org/art/216044) commissioned by [Aga Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aga_Khan), with a [ta'liq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%CA%BFl%C4%ABq_script) inscription that described its relief as the: "likeness of the incomparable Muhammad Shah, a heaven of grandeur, a vessel of beauty".

[image]
[image]
*<sup>(1) Qajar dagger with ivory hilt "carved with panels of Qajar princes, with attendants, between stylised Islamic script" - Philip Carrol Antiques (2)  ivory hilt inscribed with "the bending dagger in the hand of the Prince who dominates, is like a crescent (moon) in the hand of the sun".</sup>*

Other common inscriptions include Koran verses, prayers, or [signatures by the artisans](http://www.sothebys.com/en/auctions/ecatalogue/2008/arts-of-the-islamic-world-l08222/lot.216.html). However, it also appears that sometimes the "inscriptions" are actually just stylised scripts meant as **decorations**. Given that users @tohuwawohu and @moudiz said the inscriptions in the OP's images are not intelligible Arabic, this may well be the case here.